# IntegrityError: null value in column "invoiceOwner_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In my django app, i'm having difficulties whenever i want to add a new object that uses the table **paymentInvoice**.

The error i'm getting from my api looks like this

> **IntegrityError at /api/clients/invoice/
> null value in column "invoiceOwner_id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (10, INV-0006, Lix, 2020-08-04, 1, Pending, 3000, null).**

**NB:** I haven't created the field `invoiceOwner_id`, postgres automatically added it or rather is using it as a representation for my `invoiceOwner` field

```
class Purchaser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='customer_photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    data_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class paymentInvoice(models.Model):

    invoiceNo = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default=increment_invoice_number)
    invoiceOwner = models.ForeignKey(Purchaser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="invoice_detail")
    product = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=1)
    payment_made = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoiceOwner.name
```

**serilizers** file

```
class paymentInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    invoiceOwner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = paymentInvoice
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_invoiceOwner(self, instance):
        return instance.invoiceOwner.name
```

**views** file

```
class paymentInvoiceListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = paymentInvoiceSerializer
    queryset = paymentInvoice.objects.all().order_by('-date')
```

`GET` result from api call.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "invoiceOwner": "Martin",
    "invoiceNo": "INV-0001",
     "product": "",
    "date": "2020-08-04",
    "quantity": 1,
    "payment_made": 0
}
```

Tried passing below as `POST` but got the main error

```
{
    "invoiceOwner": "Becky",
    "product": "Lix",
    "quantity": 1,
    "payment_made": 3000
}
```

Comment: You need to explicitly override the `create` method in your  serializer since your model as foreign key `invoiceOwner`, just to create that instance first as a `Purchaser` instance

Comment: I tried but got stuck. How would i go about doing that. Use the provided code

Answer (score 0):

"invoiceOwner" in your serializers.py is a SerializerMethodField which is [readonly](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)
that's why you get an error, you have to define the create method yourself

Comment: Kindly assist with the **create** method using the above code

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment: You need to explicitly override the create method in your serializer since your model has foreign key invoiceOwner, just to create that instance first as a Purchaser instance.

You can try the code below:

```
class paymentInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    invoiceOwner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = paymentInvoice
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_invoiceOwner(self, instance):
        return instance.invoiceOwner.name

   def create(self, validated_data):
        purchaser_name = validated_data.get("invoiceOwner") 
        purchaser = Purchaser(name=purchaser_name,
            # you need to have phone, email, since these fields are unique,
            # they can't remain null
        )
        purchaser.save()
        return paymentInvoice.objects.create(invoiceOwner = purchaser, **validated_data)
```

Comment: they can be null with `null=True, blank=True`, but the problem in your code, is the `unique=True` that will cause problems with at least 2 instances with null values ... 2 instances with null values for the same fields are not unique

Comment: I have removed the unique attribute and added ``blank=True`` but when i try to create the new object after adding your func i get an error ``ValueError at /api/clients/invoice/ save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'invoiceOwner'.``

Comment: it means that an instance that has been used, is not saved. I suspect you did not save the Purchaser, I updated my answer

Comment: My bad, your the field name is not `name`, but instead: `invoiceOwner` based on the data you posted. e.g: `"invoiceOwner": "Becky",`. Answer updated

Comment: As I said in the answer, did you add `null=True` to the 2 fields that will remain empty or even null? `phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)` and  also for phone

Comment: neither has ``null=True``, i only used ``blank=True`` for both

Comment: `blank=True` is for Django side, it decides whether the value can be empty or not... null=True, is db side in case your fields will receive null value (this is your case). So they should have `null=True` otherwise you will have `IntegrityError null value in column "fiel_name" violates not-null constraint`... and please tell me witch error feedback that you have, the error may be the same, but for another field which is null

Comment: I have set both ``null=True`` only problem is the **invoiceOwner** is set to null instead of the name i have passed (e.g Becky)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219213/discussion-between-lemayzeur-and-shadow-walker).